# 2 page validation error handling Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've got a comment form on my page (commentlist) and want validate this. The form submits to another url: comment/add. The validation itself works perfectly but I can't display the messages with form_errors(form) into the form field.

I know this is because the validation exists out of 2 pages. So it's being validated but then redirected again to the page so that it looks like there are no mistakes.

**my question:**
What's the best way to transfer the messages to my formpage so that I can show them to the user? Preferabbly to keep the submitted message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flash messages. You can set the message into the action:

```
$this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Flash label!");
```

and you can show it into the template:

```
 {% for key, flash in app.session.getFlashes() %}
    <div class="errors">
        {{ flash }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks, But I found out that it's not $this->getUser(). It's: $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Flash label!");  source: http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/07/symfony2-setting-flash-messages/ Thanks for putting me on the right track.